# How to change account in PyCharme [to commit from different gitlab account]

Tags: git, pycharm, gitlab

Can you please help. I am using PyCharme to work on the same projects in a team.
And I am using a PC from previous developer, now I want to commit my work from my username.
How do I do that?

I searched all over PyCharme, did not find how to do this. PyCharme does not provides settings page for gitlab account (onlu github). Does reinstalling PyCharme and cloning our repo from scratch is the only option ?

Many thanks if anyone can clarify !

Comment: I don't think there's a operation in PyCharm for this, AFAIK. It simply depends on your `git` configuration. You just have to set it in the terminal using, `git config`

Comment: Actually when I reinstalled PyCharme and configured my account, now commit events are done from my name but push events are traced still from old accound